# Can I embed Google Drive in a web page?

Tags: google-drive, embed

Google Sites and Calendar and various other services have frames you can embed in other sites. In particular Google Groups has a particularly decent embed functionality.

Security issues aside, I would like to be able to embed drive folders on a page the same way as conversations from Groups. With groups, you can use simple HTML code from the Google service and just add it to your existing page. It would be a good thing to have a user-friendly without delving too deep into APIs.

Is there a way to use a similar embed code with a shared folder of Google Drive using either Google code or an embed from an outside service?

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26407/what-services-can-i-add-from-google-drive-to-my-website & read this article: http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/04/google-drive-sdk-announced-but-apis-are-only-accesible-to-web-apps-for-now/ - It seems that there is some sort of API support for websites, but I think it's still limited.

Comment: You can just turn your folder public and create a website out of it and the internal files

Comment: @phwd I have updated the question to emphasize that I am looking for an answer based on whether there is a similar embed code as there is with the other services; individuals leveraging the API seems unnecessary based on the various other services providing code for a similar feature

Comment: This should help: [How to embed a Google Drive folder in a website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20681974/478018)

Comment: @RainLover since Google App policy may have changed since the last answer was accepted, you can post your answer here and I can accept that one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

I just wrote a [blog post](https://mori.pages.dev/blog/embed-google-drive-folders) and created an embed code generator to make your life a bit easier.

---

1. Go to your Google Drive.
2. Right-click on the folder.
3. Select **Share**.
4. Open the **General access** drop-down menu.
5. Select **Anyone with the link** to publish your folder.
6. Click **Copy link** and then **Done**.
   You will get a URL like the following:
   [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/**1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa**?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa?usp=sharing)
   You can see your folder ID in bold: **1qGwpjmQIQO8rN1odas0njDSf72VRrTCa**
7. Google Drive folders can be embedded and displayed in `list` and `grid` views. Put the folder ID in one of the following `iframe` sources:

### List view

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

### Grid view

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

Google Drive does not provide HTML embed codes directly, and they actively block the ability to put a public folder listing in an `<iframe>` on your website (using `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`).

I have been unable to find a third-party service that provides embedding functionality.

Your answer at this time appears to be **No**.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that the answer lies in the use of Google API service. I have been looking at the same thing and so far this is the answer.

https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries

You need to add the client library to your website and reference it in your webpages. You also need to add a security key to Google so that the system can authenticate the call from your site to your Google drive.

The same library's work for Tasks, Email, Calendar and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

1. Upload your PDF file.
2. Then click your file in document list.
3. A preview will be opened.
4. You will see a blue button named *Open* (right-bottom side)
5. Click that button. You will be transferred docs.google.com
6. Here you will see the top-menu like *File*, *Edit*...
7. Choose *File* → *Embed file*. Then you can get an embed code.

Also, don't forget that your document’s sharing settings must be *anyone with the link*.

Answer (score 1):

I found one article that might help you out.

This article shows you how to embed a list of Google Docs in a Page on your Google Site. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites. It requires a bit of scripting knowledge so it might be a little advanced depending on how comfortable you are.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081488/embedding-google-doclist-in-a-google-site-script-failing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162349/retrieving-google-drive-folder-contents-versus-google-docs-folder-what-is-diff) are questions on the SE Network concerning the script.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to integrate Google Sites and Google Drive is MetaDrive. http://www.evenbytes.com/metadrive.html

This tool allow users to display a Drive Folder, browse, search and some advance functionalities like custom metadata

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Picker Instead:
https://developers.google.com/picker

The other methods might not work but this is guarenteed to work.